# Please help me write this jQuery statement

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, keycode

If there is an image on the document that has a class of "something" and the down arrow (key 40) is pressed then run function .setNextPage.

Here is the code I have so far: (the down arrow to trigger the function works, just need to add in the need for the second condition to be met)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
   setNextPage('720/GIJoe/main.txt', 'ele1');
   return false;
} });
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40 && $('img.something').length > 0) { 
       setNextPage('720/GIJoe/main.txt', 'ele1');
       return false;
    } 
});
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked. Thanks for helping out, I still have a bunch to learn. I am going to deep dive into understanding .length.

Comment: `.length` in this context returns the count of matching elements. Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.keyCode == 40 && $('.something').length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if theres an element existing in the DOM by using the native javascript .length function.

```
if(e.keyCode == 40 && $('img.something').length) {
     //code
}
```

if there isn't an img element with the class of something, it will return false and the statement won't run.